# Enviar uma lista a uma web api utilizando $http.put do AngularJS

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net, angularjs, entity-framework

Estou tendo problemas para conseguir enviar uma lista utilizando o método $http.put do angularjs, consigo enviar um objeto normalmente, mais uma lista não está seguindo, alguém tem algum exemplo de código para que eu possa tirar essa dúvida ou passar um link de algum material a respeito, desde já deixo meu agradecimento...

Atendendo ao pedido do Paulo segue:

Eu tenho uma lista que apresento na tela na qual vou buscar através de web api utilizando AngularJs para fazer a requisição get, segue:

```
$http.get(urlService + "?idUsuario=" + usuario.IdUsuario).success(function (result, status, headers, config) {
            // Ordena pela idade do usuário
            var byId = function (a, b) {
                if (a.IdSolicitacao > b.IdSolicitacao)
                    return -1;
                if (a.IdSolicitacao < b.IdSolicitacao)
                    return 1;
                return 0;
            }
            $scope.listaSolicitacoes = result;//.sort(byId);
            var largura = $('.wraper').width();
            var altura = (43 * largura) / 100;

            $('.panel-body').css('max-height', Math.round(altura) + 'px');
        }).error(function (response) {
            MsgBox("Error", "Ocorreu um problema ao carregar os dados das solicitações.\n" + response, "error");
        });
```

o que acontece é que eu faço edições direto nesta lista no html e após essas mudanças eu pego uma lista(array) com os dados dessa lista já alterado...o que ocorre é que não quero mandar uma por uma para o banco para serem atualizados apenas os dados alterados, gostaria de enviar esta lista para a web api e lá utilizando C# com Entity Framework eu percorreria esta lista efetuando as alterações e no fim dando um SaveChanges() geral, ou seja, comitando tudas as alterações de uma só vez.

Se eu fizer uma requisição para cada alteração vai ficar muita requisição a base de dados...

segue a função do angular que faz a requisição e em seguida a web api em c# como estou implementando:

```
var UpdateLista = function () {
        $http.put(urlService, angular.toJson($scope.listaSolicitacoes)).success(function (result, status, headers, config) {

        }).error(function (response) {
            MsgBox("Error", "Não foi possível atualizar a prioridade.\n" + response, "error");
        });
    }
```

Função da WebAPI:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(List<SolicitacaoModel> listaSolicitacao)
    {
        try
        {
            using (kurierPortalQualidadeEntities ctx = new kurierPortalQualidadeEntities())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < listaSolicitacao.Count; i++)
                {
                    Solicitacao sol = new Solicitacao();
                    sol.IdSolicitacao   = listaSolicitacao[i].IdSolicitacao;
                    sol.Assunto = listaSolicitacao[i].Assunto;
                    sol.DataSolicitacao = listaSolicitacao[i].DataSolicitacao;
                    sol.Descricao = ctx.Solicitacao.Where(s => s.IdSolicitacao == sol.IdSolicitacao).FirstOrDefault().Descricao;
                    sol.IdProjeto = ctx.Solicitacao.Where(p => p.DescricaoProjeto == listaSolicitacao[i].Produto).FirstOrDefault().IdProjeto;
                    sol.DescricaoProjeto = listaSolicitacao[i].Produto;
                    sol.IdUsuario = Convert.ToInt32(listaSolicitacao[i].IdUsuario);
                    sol.Usuario = ctx.Usuario.Where(u => u.IdUsuario == sol.IdUsuario).FirstOrDefault();
                    sol.Prioridade = Convert.ToInt32(listaSolicitacao[i].Prioridade);
                    sol.SolicitacaoAprovacao = ctx.SolicitacaoAprovacao.Where(sa => sa.IdSolicitacao == listaSolicitacao[i].IdSolicitacao).ToList();
                    sol.Anexo = ctx.Anexo.Where(a => a.IdSolicitação == sol.IdSolicitacao).ToList();


                    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadGateway, ModelState);
                    }
                    ctx.Entry(sol).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadGateway, e);
        }
    }
```

Segue toda a Exception que me retorna:

> ExceptionMessage: "Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
>   ↵Put on type PortalDeQualidade.Controllers.SolicitacaoController
>   ↵Put on type PortalDeQualidade.Controllers.SolicitacaoController"
>   ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException"
>   Message: "An error has occurred."
>   StackTrace: " em System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
>   ↵ em System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
>   ↵ em System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   ↵ em System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"

Comment: Poderia por favor postar o que você tem até o momento?:

Comment: Paulo, editei a pergunta, veja se dá para entender melhor o que eu quero fazer, obrigado!

Comment: Um modo é: você criar uma lista nova, e sempre que um item for alterado, você coloca ele dentro desta lista. e no final você envia ela para ser atualizada.

Comment: Meu problema não esta em obter essa lista atualizada e sim como enviar essa lista para a web api, estou tentando com $http.put como vc pode ver no código em UpdateLista() mais o mesmo não aceita o envio, sempre dar erro no tipo que estou enviando para web api, quero saber como envio uma lista usando o $http.put() do angularjs...entende?

Comment: aaah ta, qual erro que da?

Comment: O material que existe, tem no site do prório AngularJs:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: Tal como @PauloHDSousa disse nos comentários em cima, é um problema de routing. O algoritmo de routing do asp.net está a encontrar duas funções para o método PUT. Dito isto, o melhor é editar o post original e adicionar a tabela de routing (definida em WebApiConfig.cs ou semelhante) e o esqueleto (definição das funções) do controlador correpondente.